# Why do I need to convert a list to IEnumerable when the list is already iterable?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable, ienumerator

I understand the difference between IEnumerable and IEnumerator. But I don't quite think of when I should convert my list to IEnumerable. Isn't a list already iterable? Some tutorials shows foreach example to explain IEnumerable. But isn't a list also working exactly same way as IEnumerable? Please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an interface, and [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) implements it, so there is no "conversion" needed. Can you give an example of what you're asking?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a misunderstanding between "casting" and "conversion".

Comment: When you post * Some tutorials shows foreach example to explain IEnumerable* you should actually link those so we have some context about your question.  As your question stands, it is not answer-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `List<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`. So is an array, and so are numerous other classes. When we say that it is an `IEnumerable<T>` we mean that it implements that interface.

So if I have this method:

```
void PrintStringsToConsole(IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    foreach(var s in strings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Any of these will work. You don't have to convert anything.

```
var stringArray = new string[] {"a", "b", "c"};
PrintStringsToConsole(stringArray);

var stringList = new List<string> {"x", "y", "z"};
PrintStringsToConsole(stringList);

var hashSet = new HashSet<string> {"a","b","c"};
PrintStringsToConsole(hashSet);

var filteredList = stringList.Where(s => s != "a"); 
PrintStringsToConsole(filteredList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you don’t need to convert you List to IEnumerable.  I’m assuming that you’re talking about a method signature that specifies an IEnumerable type as a parameter, and it’s merely a way for the method to accept any collection that implements the interface as opposed to explicitly declare an override for each type of collection.